# Is there any way to tell which Heart Container Pieces I already have?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

I recently continued my Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask from where I'd left it off several months ago.

Is there any way to tell which of the 52 heart container pieces I already have so I don't waste my time trying to find ones I've already collected?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to identify which containers were already collected in any of the games.  You're SOL I think unless you could remember which ones you had gotten or just go down the list checking again.

Comment: If you're using an emulator I'm sure you could find where that data is stored in the saved state ... I'm not confident that there would be a handy checklist you could follow for that, though.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Well it is technically an emulator, it's the one that Nintendo packages with Majora's Mask when you buy it from the Wii Shop Channel.

Comment: I eventually just decided to not try to get all the heart pieces, particularly after I discovered how hard some of the minigame ones were to get.  I think I was missing 10/52 pieces at the end of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, remember which ones you got and get the other ones. Other than that you're on your own.

I got my hands on a guide to find where they all are and printed it out and physically ticked them off as I got them. That's your best bet.

Comment: GameFAQs has scads of guides, even one [just for the heart pieces](http://www.gamefaqs.com/n64/197770-the-legend-of-zelda-majoras-mask/faqs/9473).

Comment: Sadly, the several month gap between when I got to dungeon 3 and went back to beat it and continue the game meant I would have had to have said checklist back then.

Comment: It shouldn't matter too much, just try to get all of them and if they're not there, you must have got it already.

Comment: Luckily, the 3DS version tracks quests, so the majority of them can be tracked that way.

Comment: I used a guide, also. 52 is a lot to remember. (When playing through OoT, with a mere 36 heart pieces, I didn't use a guide and didn't keep track... and then couldn't find the last one at the end and had to retrace a lot of steps.)

Answer (score 0):

No *Zelda* game provides any tracking mechanism for heart containers other than the health bar. Your only option to go to the area and see if it looks familiar, or talk to the people to see if you finished their sidequest.

So if you do want to track them, you will have to either write it down or use a checklist.

Comment: In Twilight Princess you can have the fortune teller tell you where a heart piece is. This is a very limited tracking system in that you are guaranteed that the fortune teller will only show you heart pieces still available.